# This program is blocked by group policy. in godaddy windows hosting

Tags: plesk, windows-hosting

I am trying to execute a `.exe` file through Scheduled Tasks in **Godaddy** but when this task is run there is an error of

> "This program is blocked by group policy".

Application is a C# console application.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

In the web.config, comment out everything within `<system.codedom>`. GoDaddy blocks it.

```
<!--<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
</compilers>-->
```