# Executing an exe file on Plesk

Tags: asp.net, process, exe, plesk, group-policy

I have created a web app using Asp.net and I have published my website on my domain(I'm using Plesk) and the website is functioning correctly. In one of my pages I execute an exe file in code behind which returns an output, which then will be printed in the page. It works correctly on local host, but on Plesk I get the error "This program is blocked by group policy". This is while I have set the CAS trust level to Full, I've enabled the "precompilie during publishing" option when I published the web app. I've erased the `<system.codedom>` tag in web.config, but the issue is still not fixed.

Here is the stack trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +1889
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +119
   Project.StyleSheets.Result.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Soroush\Programming\Spark\Project\Project\Result.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Line 24 is the line at which I start the exe file, namely I execute the following code:

```
Process compiler = new Process();
            compiler.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Program/dist/News-Fetcher/News-Fetcher.exe");
            compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", Request.QueryString["search"]);
            compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Line24:            compiler.Start();
```

How can I solve his problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Administrator RDP access to the server?
Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567745/